# How can create css3 button?

Tags: css

How can I create a button like the picture by css3 ?

[image]

I've tried the following code.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .left,
    .right{
        float:left;
  border-style:solid;  
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
    }
    .left{
        border-color: red green red green;
        border-width:15px 0px 15px 75px;
    }
    .right{
  border-color: green green green red;
  border-width:15px 20px 15px 35px;
    }  
</style>
<div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

but got like this output:

[image]

Whats the exact way to create curved border of buttons and thin curve between two buttons ?

-Thanks.

***EDIT***: according to your answers I've made this :

```
<style type="text/css">    
    .left,
    .middle,
    .right{
        height:30px;         
        display:block;
        float:left;
        text-decoration:none;
        position: relative;
        text-align:center;
        color:black;        
    }
    .left,
    .right{
        padding:0px 10px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }   
    .left{
        background-color:red;
        width:60px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
        border-top-left-radius: 17px;
    }
    .middle{
        background-color:#ddd;
        width:2px; 
    }    
    .right{
        background-color:green;
        width:40px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 17px;
        border-top-right-radius: 17px;        
    }
    .middle::before{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px; 
        margin-top: -5px;
        border-width: 15px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd transparent;
        left: -15px;
    } 
    .right::before{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px; 
        margin-top: -5px;
        border-width: 15px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: green transparent green transparent;
        left: -15px;
    }
    .left:hover{
        background-color:blue;
    }
    .right:hover{
        background-color:orange;
    }
    .right:hover::before{
        border-color: orange transparent orange transparent;
    }
</style>

<a href="javascript:void();" class="left">play</a>
<a href="javascript:void();" class="middle"></a>
<a href="javascript:void();" class="right">pause</a>
```

output:

[image]

is it ok for standard website ?

Comment: Did you just delete and re-post this question to remove the critical comments?

Comment: I was thinking the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:-

```
<style type="text/css">
    .left,.right,a{
        float:left;
        border-style:solid;  
        width:0px;
        height:0px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .left{
        border-color: 0A0D6A;
        border-width:10px 0px 10px 30px;
    }
    .right{
        border-color: 6568B9 6568B9 6568B9 0A0D6A;
        border-width:10px 30px 10px 8px;
        margin-left:-3px;
    }  
</style>
<div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Creating the white boundary between the blues with pure css is tricky. Same goes for the "speaker" and "play" icons but i'm sure in future, CSS4 will make this one easier for all of us :).
 In the mean time, simple images will work fine.
[image]

## EDIT:- Here's 2 ways of getting the "color change on hover" effect you requested:

**Method #1, harnessing the css "hover selector" of the parent div**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .left,.right,a{
        float:left;
        border-style:solid;  
        width:0px;
        height:0px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .left{
        border-color:#0A0D6A;
        border-width:10px 0px 10px 30px;
    }
    .right{
        border-color:#6568B9 #6568B9 #6568B9 #0A0D6A;
        border-width:10px 30px 10px 8px;
        margin-left:-3px;
    }  
    #top:hover .left{ border-color:#00FF55;cursor:pointer; }
    #top:hover .right{ border-color:#6568B9 #6568B9 #6568B9 #00FF55; }  
</style>
<div id=top>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**Method #2 harnessing the css "next sibling selector" of the .left classed div**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .left,.right,a{
        float:left;
        border-style:solid;  
        width:0px;
        height:0px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .left{
        border-color:#0A0D6A;
        border-width:10px 0px 10px 30px;
    }
    .right{
        border-color:#6568B9 #6568B9 #6568B9 #0A0D6A;
        border-width:10px 30px 10px 8px;
        margin-left:-3px;
    }  
    .left:hover { border-color:#00FF55;cursor:pointer; }
    .left:hover +div{ border-color:#6568B9 #6568B9 #6568B9 #00FF55; }  
</style>
<div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

### Check whether they both work on iexplore < 9

Comment: thanks for your help... can you tell me how could I change color of the left button for hover (as it also would be required to change color of the left border of the right button for that) ?

Comment: @user1844626 Checkout the edits i've provided to sort your request

Comment: @user1844626 Very creative. I like it. The only thing left is to optimize the amount of text required to define the CSS. e.g. You don't need :display:block for the <a> buttons and you can declare various css propertirs in one line...e.g for .right class, "border-radius: 17px;" alone is enough. Also as you optimise, continuously check whether your page renders on all MAJOR & MODERN browsers (with IEXPLORE being >= v9).

Answer (score 2):

Actually the best solution to this is that.......... the button is three images... if you want to use the two parts of buttons separately.

**1st** - The left side button

**2nd** - The junction where you see the transition

**3rd** - The right side part.

You can also use `color` and `image`.

**1st** - The left side button `color`

**2nd** - The junction where you see the transition `image`

**3rd** - The right side button `color`.

This is the way most of the webpages do..

Comment: so it needs to use a transparent background image for that if I want to change color of the buttons for hover,right ? but IE older version doesn't support transparent background well,is there any trick for that ?

Comment: Actually what you are talking cannot be achieved using buttons, it can be achieved using `span` with no gaps between the elements so that two spans seems to be same. But Actually three `spans`. One `left button`, `one right button` and third in `middle` which will change its background image using javascript. then you can do this. As button is one element and you cannot divide `ActionListener` of button in HTML based on where you mouse position is.

Comment: It is better you use `span` and apply `onClick` it will act as button. I have used this in many websites. and it works fine. better than any button.